# How to perform MySQL 'SUM' but to '0' decimal places?

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, numbers, currency

I have a MySQL table containing account balances, which are stored as floats, with two decimal places, in a `varbinary` column type (because the values are AES_ENCRYPTED).

I realise that it's not ideal storing values as floats and in later tables they no longer are, but I can't do anything about this legacy table yet, so need to work with it as is.

I'm trying to compute the sum of all the balances, which I was able to do with the code below:

```
$s=$dbh->prepare("
    SELECT
        SUM(AES_DECRYPT(a.acct_balance, '".DBKEY."'))   AS tBal
    FROM
        accounts a
    INNER JOIN
        coa c
    ON
        a.acc_id = c.acc_id
    WHERE
        c.acc_type_id = ?
    AND
        a.acc_type = 1
");
```

However, some reports also display the balances individually to zero decimal spaces and if you add those up, you usually get a different result to the above query which is computed using values to two decimal places, even after converting the result to zero decimal places.

I think I need to inform MySQL to temporarily convert each value to zero decimal spaces before adding it to the running total, but how would I do that?

The values I'm displaying in the report are converted using:

```
$val = number_format($val, 0, '', ',');
```

Comment: Do not store money as floats as you are subject to rounding errors. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html for DECIMAL/NUMERIC data types that preserve precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be as simple as this?

```
SUM(ROUND(AES_DECRYPT(a.acct_balance, '".DBKEY."')))
```

That will make a sum of the rounded values

Answer (score 1):

You can try ROUND function like

```
ROUND(SUM(AES_DECRYPT(a.acct_balance, '".DBKEY."')))
```

Comment: This works in my example right now, but I think the accepted answer is probably more correct in ordering of the functions (SUM then Round). +1 for speedy answer and bringing `ROUND` to my attention.